# How to create a dataframe from existing data frame where few column are appended as rows?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, row

I have a data frame like below:

```
data = {'Age': [20, 30, 19, 21],'city1':['ny','nj','ln','tampa'],'country1':['usa','usa','usa','usa'],'city2':['london','edinburg',np.nan,'tampa'],
        'country2':['uk','uk','uk','usa'],
        'city1':['ny','london',np.nan,np.nan],'country2':['usa','uk',np.nan,np.nan]}  
df1=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df1)
    Age city1   country1    city2   country2
0   20  ny      usa        london    usa
1   30  london  usa        edinburg  uk
2   19  NaN     usa        NaN       NaN
3   21  NaN     usa        tampa     NaN
```

Now I want to create a new data frame where the `age` column values are repeated based on the half of the number of columns leaving the `age` column. In above data frame leaving age column there are four column who's half is 2. So, the age column values have to be repeated twice. Once the new age column is formed then I need to append `city1,` `country1` has a row and `city2,country2` as a second row(something like shown in the excepted output). Although I was able to repeat the values as list and tried to get the values as a list from the other columns and append as rows like shown below:-

```
code:-
#for repeating the value.
main_list = np.repeat(df1['Age'],2)
#for getting the column values 
r=[]
for i in range(len(df1)):
    r.append(df1.iloc[:,1:3].loc[i].values.tolist())
print(r)
[['ny', 'usa'], ['london', 'usa'], [nan, 'usa'], [nan, 'usa']]
```

but as you see it gives only the values for `city1,country1` but not for `city2,country2` which is raising an error when appending the list r values as rows to the new data frame as below:-

```
newdata = {'Age':main_list}
res=pd.DataFrame(newdata)
print(res)
   Age
0   20
0   20
1   30
1   30
2   19
2   19
3   21
3   21

res.loc[len(res)] = r
print(res)
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

How do I get the excepted list of values and create a data frame like below:-

Excepted output:-

```
r =[['ny', 'usa'], ['london', 'usa'],['london', 'usa'],['edinburg','uk'],
                     [nan, 'usa'],[nan,nan],[nan, 'usa'],['tampa',nan]]
```

Final data frame:-

```
   Age  city     country
0   20  'ny'     'usa'
0   20  'london' 'usa'
1   30  'london' 'usa'
1   30  'edinburg''uk'
2   19   NaN     'usa'
2   19   NaN      NaN
3   21   NaN     'usa'
3   21  'tampa'  NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
(pd
 .wide_to_long(df1.reset_index(),
               stubnames=['city', 'country'], i=['index', 'Age'], j='id')
 .droplevel(-1)
 .reset_index('Age')
)
```

output:

```
       Age      city country
index                       
0       20        ny     usa
0       20    london     usa
1       30    london     usa
1       30  edinburg      uk
2       19       NaN     usa
2       19       NaN     NaN
3       21       NaN     usa
3       21     tampa     NaN
```

Comment: This looks alight but what is j?

Comment: This is the name of the column that catches the number in the initial columns names (city*1*, country*1*). We need to provide a name, even if we drop it later like in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the function `pivot_longer` provided by `janitor`:

```
import janitor
df1.pivot_longer('Age', names_to = ['.value', 'group'], names_pattern = '(\\D+)(\\d+)')

   Age group      city country
0   20     1        ny     usa
1   30     1    london     usa
2   19     1       NaN     usa
3   21     1       NaN     usa
4   20     2    london     usa
5   30     2  edinburg      uk
6   19     2       NaN     NaN
7   21     2     tampa     NaN
```